# Give examples of functions that satisfy all but one property of metrics

Tags: metric-spaces

> A function $d: \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}$ iff all of the following holds:
>
> 1. $d(x,y)\geq0 \;\forall x,y $
> 2. $d(x,y)=0 \iff x=y$
> 3. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
> 4. Triangle inequaliy

The exercise asks us to give one example of function that satisfies all of the conditions above but one (for each condition).

I was successfull on 2.: $d(x,y)=\vert x-y\vert +1$ do satisfies 1,3,4 but not 2., right?

On the others I got stuck, I tried floor and ceil things, sums, multiplications... nothing did work.

Could you help me? (I'm sorry if it is duplicated, I couldn't find something like this)

Edit: I could do 4. too, but it isn't a "beautiful" example I think: $d(x,y)=\begin{cases}\vert x-y\vert-5, \mbox{ if }\vert x-y\vert >5
\\\vert x-y\vert, \mbox{ otherwise}\end{cases}$, then we have $d(1,15)>d(1,7)+d(7,15)$ for example.

Comment: For (2), why not just take $d = 1$?

Comment: That's right!..

Comment: For a failure only of the forward direction of (2), try something like $d(x,y)=0$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Generalized_metrics

Comment: @Surb , thanks! Now I just don't have an example for 1.

Comment: @Robson you can't find such an example, as stated in the wikipedia article: "The first condition is implied by the others." https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131878/proving-that-a-metric-is-non-negative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After all the comments here, which I thank all you for, I can summarize an answer for my question.

**First case:** After all, properties 2,3,4 implies 1. In fact,: $0 = d(x,x)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,x)=2d(x,y)$ hence $d(x,y)\geq 0 \; \forall x,y$. Thus it is impossible to give na example of function that satisfy 2-4 but not 1.

**Second case:** $d(x,y)=1 \; \forall x,y$ will do.

**Third case**: $ d(x,y)=\begin{cases}x-y, \mbox{ if x}\geq y\\1, \mbox{ otherwise }  \end{cases}$ is enough.

**Fourth case**: $d(x,y)=\vert x-y\vert ^2$

Answer (score 3):

For a nicer solution to (4), try $$d(x,y)=|x-y|^2$$
$d(0,1)=1>0.5=0.25+0.25=d(0,0.5)+d(0.5,1)$

The relevant jargon for these four functions is found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Generalized_metrics), where functions omitting (2) are called pseudometrics or metametrics, functions omitting (3) are called quasimetrics, functions omitting (4) are called semimetrics.  No mention of omitting (1), because that seems to be [impossible](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1131878/73324).

Comment: +1, Can I know the motivation ?

Comment: It's a nonlinear function.