# Question regarding subspaces and dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a hw question I am stuck on.

Two vectors spaces $X$ and $Y$ are two subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ If $\dim(X)$ + $\dim(Y) > n$, how can I prove that there must exist a non-zero vector in their intersection?

I know that the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $n$, but this is where I'm kinda stuck.
Any help or useful links would be appreciated. I've been googling to no resources to avail so far

Comment: As originally written, your question was missing context. I believe I have fixed the issue, but please clarify if this was not the correct edit.

Comment: Should your condition be "If $\dim(U)+\dim(V)>n$"?

Comment: Are you sure dim$(U)>n$ and dim$(V)>n$? Subspaces have dimension no greater than the ambient space.

Comment: I have correctly edited my post.

Comment: Contrapositively, if $X \cap Y = {0}$, then $X + Y = X \oplus Y \subseteq \Bbb R^n$...

Comment: The proof will be based on the fact that they will intersect at the zero vector.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose not. That is, $\dim(X)+\dim(Y)>n \ $ but $\ X\cap Y = \{ 0\}$.

We have the formula (here is a [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897708/give-examples-of-functions-that-satisfy-all-but-one-property-of-metrics/2898901#2898901) on this formula) $$\dim(X+Y)=\dim(X)+\dim(Y)-\dim(X\cap Y)$$

Then if the intersection is $\{0\}$ we have that $\dim(X+Y)=\dim(X)+\dim(Y)>n$, but $X+Y$ is in a vector space with dimension $n$; *contradiction!*